# Parched grain at seder

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, dagan-five-grains

[Pesachim 109a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.109a.1) has קליות given to the kids at Seder.  Is there an issue of this "parched grain" being chametz?  How would it be made?  Like matzah?  How would they make it appealing to kids?

Comment: The beginning of https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/04-02-07/ may be relevant.

Comment: Dry toasting fresh wheat grains doesn't present any problem of chametz, since even if some juice oozed out from one grain onto another it is like fruit juice and doesn't cause the wheat to ferment

Shulchan Arukh OC 463:1 (I don't know if that is what they would use for kids, but it seemingly could have been)

Comment: OC 208 4 sounds like toasted wheat was indeed a common snack, but not toasted barley.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fSY4YCVSoM It's just like popcorn (which is also kosher lepesach, even for ashkenazim if you can find corn to use that's never been washed)

Comment: I just tried it here at home and while the wheat berries are definitely crispier toasted it wasn't the major change I was expecting. Maybe it's because my wheat isn't super fresh or something.

Comment: @DoubleAA Would you say they're good enough to eat and feed kids without them being picky about it

Comment: @Aaron Maybe if the kids hadn't grown up with high fructose corn syrup in everything they eat. They were sort of like toasty nuts. I suspect more practice would yield a better result though.

Comment: @DoubleAA My child loves nuts. Did you follow a particular set of directions or did you just throw some in a frying pan? (Note: One of the upsides of covid is my daughter has never had high fructose corn syrup)